# g++ and clang++ different behaviour with friend template function defined inside a template class

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, friend

Another question of type "who's right between g++ and clang++?" for C++ standard gurus.

The following code

```
template <int>
struct foo
 {
   template <typename>
   friend void bar ()
    { }
 };

int main ()
 {    
   foo<0>  f0;
   foo<1>  f1;
 }
```

compile without problem with clang++ (only two "unused variable" warnings) but give a the following error

```
tmp_002-11,14,gcc,clang.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct foo<1>’:
tmp_002-11,14,gcc,clang.cpp:27:12:   required from here
tmp_002-11,14,gcc,clang.cpp:20:16: error: redefinition of ‘template<class> void bar()’
    friend void bar ()
                ^~~
tmp_002-11,14,gcc,clang.cpp:20:16: note: ‘template<class> void bar()’ previously defined here
```

compiling with g++.

The question, as usual, is: who's right ? g++ or clang++ ?

Checked with clang++ 3.9.1 and g++ 6.3.0 in my Debian platform. But, trying in Wandbox, seems equals with more recent versions.

Comment: You can simplify your code by removing `template <typename>` and get the same error with GCC.

Comment: @NeilButterworth - I know: in that case, I have the same error with both compilers.

Comment: For extra fun: https://godbolt.org/g/y7mtWX Regardless of what the standard says, surely this has to be a clang bug as well, it makes no sense that changing the order of the `f0` and `f1` definitions changes the result without any diagnostic whatsoever.

Comment: Even more fun: If you declare the function in global namespace: `template <typename> void bar();` and leave just *one* variable, then call to `bar<int>();` compiles on GCC and results in 'undefined reference' on Clang.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44268181/2752075): *"CWG agreed that such techniques (stateful template metaprogramming by defining friend functions in templates) should be ill-formed, although the mechanism for prohibiting them is as yet undetermined."* I wasn't able to find one, but maybe there is some related defect report?

Comment: @hvd - surprising; seems that the second definition cover the first one.

Comment: Currently clang has some problems with friends, see [bug 33222](https://llvm.org/pr33222). Probably related

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GCC is right in this case.

The relevant standard wording is in [[temp.inst]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#2):

> The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes
>   — the implicit instantiation of the declarations, but not of the
>   definitions, of the non-deleted class member functions, member
>   classes, scoped member enumerations, static data members, member
>   templates, and friends; and
>   [...]
>   However, for the purpose of
>   determining whether an instantiated redeclaration is valid according
>   to 6.2 and 12.2, a declaration that corresponds to a definition in the
>   template is considered to be a definition. [ *Example:* [...]
>
> ```
> template<typename T> struct Friendly {
>    template<typename U> friend int f(U) { return sizeof(T); }
> };
> Friendly<char> fc;
> Friendly<float> ff; // ill-formed: produces second definition of f(U)
> ```
>
> *— end example* ]

The parts related to friends were added to this paragraph by [DR2174](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2174) and published in C++17 (it's a defect report, so compilers should apply it to previous standard versions as well).

---

Recent versions of MSVC and EDG in strict mode also reject the code, complaining about a redefinition.

[[temp.inject]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inject#1) is somewhat related, but it only talks about friend functions, not friend function templates:

> Friend classes or functions can be declared within a class template.
>   When a template is instantiated, the names of its friends are treated
>   as if the specialization had been explicitly declared at its point of
>   instantiation.