# Hidden friend templates in class template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, friend-function, argument-dependent-lookup

#### The original working code

I have a class template with two template parameters and an optimized `operator==` when the two types are the same and one another condition is satisfied. My original code is as follows (for demonstration purposes I make the generic comparison return `false` and the one where `T1 == T2` return `true`):

```cpp
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct my_class
{
    // A few hundred LOCs
};

template<typename U1, typename U2>
bool operator==(my_class<U1, U2> const& lhs, my_class<U1, U2> const& rhs)
{
    return false;
}

template<typename U>
auto operator==(my_class<U, U> const& lhs, my_class<U, U> const& rhs)
    -> std::enable_if_t<some_condition, bool>
{
    return true;
}
```

The idea is that the first overload of `operator==` is the default, and when both `U1` and `U2` are the same type and `some_condition` is satisfied the second overload is valid and picked as a better match.

#### The problem

I recently started implementing more and more operators in my generic libraries as [hidden friends](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/hidden-friends.html) to avoid some unwanted implicit conversions and to reduce the overload set the compiler has to choose from at namespace scope.

I first tried the most obvious approach to friends, which is to move the definitions as is in the class template and to prefix them with `friend`:

```cpp
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct my_class
{
    // A few hundred LOCs

    template<typename U1, typename U2>
    friend bool operator==(my_class<U1, U2> const& lhs, my_class<U1, U2> const& rhs)
    {
        return false;
    }

    template<typename U>
    friend auto operator==(my_class<U, U> const& lhs, my_class<U, U> const& rhs)
        -> std::enable_if_t<some_condition, bool>
    {
        return true;
    }
};
```

Much not to my surprise this didn't work and I got redefinition errors. The reason why is explained - along with a standard quote - in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50198379/1364752).

#### An attempt

We are always comparing `my_class` with matching template parameters, so I figured that I could get rid of the inner `template<typename U1, typename U2>` in the first definition, however it is trickier in the second one since the single template parameter was used to create a more specialized overload of `operator==`. Another solution would be to put that overload in a specialization of `my_class<T, T>` but since the class is big I didn't feel like duplicating its contents since pretty much everything else is the same. I could probably introduce another layer of indirection for the common code but I already have a hefty amount of indirection.

Failing that I tried to fallback to good old SFINAE to make sure that `T1` and `T2` are the same:

```cpp
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct my_class
{
    // A few hundred LOCs

    friend auto operator==(my_class const& lhs, my_class const& rhs)
        -> bool
    {
        return false;
    }

    friend auto operator==(my_class const& lhs, my_class const& rhs)
        -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T1, T2>::value && some_condition, bool>
    {
        return true;
    }
};
```

For some reason I don't claim to fully understand the second `operator==` above is actually ill-formed, but we can get around that by adding back some additional defaulted template parameters into the mix:

```cpp
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct my_class
{
    // A few hundred LOCs

    friend auto operator==(my_class const& lhs, my_class const& rhs)
        -> bool
    {
        return false;
    }

    template<typename U1=T1, typename U2=T2>
    friend auto operator==(my_class const& lhs, my_class const& rhs)
        -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<U1, U2>::value && some_condition, bool>
    {
        return true;
    }
};
```

This compiles as expected, but comparing two instances of `my_class` with matching `T1` and `T2` now returns `false` because the second overload of `operator==` is *less* specialized than the first one. An educated guess tells me that the new template layer is the reason, so I added back template parameters to the first overload of `operator==` and also an SFINAE condition which is a negation of the other one to make sure that the overload wouldn't be ambiguous with matching `T1` and `T2`:

```cpp
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct my_class
{
    // A few hundred LOCs

    template<typename U1=T1, typename U2=T2>
    friend auto operator==(my_class const& lhs, my_class const& rhs)
        -> std::enable_if_t<not(std::is_same<U1, U2>::value && some_condition), bool>
    {
        return false;
    }

    template<typename U1=T1, typename U2=T2>
    friend auto operator==(my_class const& lhs, my_class const& rhs)
        -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<U1, U2>::value && some_condition, bool>
    {
        return true;
    }
};
```

This finally gives the intended result while also providing the benefits of hidden friends, but the cost is a bit high in term of readability and maintainability.

#### Back to the question I originally meant to ask

I tried to explain my problem and rough solution and how I got to it above. My question is: is there a better way to achieve the same result (hidden friends with my code) without having to dive into all the template issues I highlighted above? Can I have such hidden friends while relying on the built-in partial ordering of function templates instead of replacing it with another layer of SFINAE as I did?

Comment: It may make sense to get rid of the implicit conversions instead of trying to make the nuisance that these cause bit smaller.

Comment: @ÖöTiib It's not so much about the implicit conversions than about learning more about this specific corner of the language and about considering what I might have missed tbh

Comment: I would perhaps use "if constexpr()" in single operator== instead of two overloads.

Answer (score 3):

Would you accept this?

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct my_class
{
    friend bool operator==(my_class const& lhs, my_class const& rhs)
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T1, T2>) {
            return condition;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm so used to having a return type of the form `decltype(returned expression)` where expression SFINAE matters that I kind of forgot about `if constexpr`. Here it surprisingly enough does solve the specific problem I have, even if might not work for the more general case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [Barton&Nackman_trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton%E2%80%93Nackman_trick) will work in your case:

See:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct my_class;
struct my_class_friend_operators
{
    template<typename U1, typename U2>
    friend bool operator==(my_class<U1, U2> const& lhs, my_class<U1, U2> const& rhs)
    {
        return false;
    }

    template<typename U>
    friend bool operator==(my_class<U, U> const& lhs, my_class<U, U> const& rhs)
    {
        return true;
    }
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct my_class : my_class_friend_operators 
{
    // A few hundred LOCs
};

int main() {
    return my_class<float,int>{} == my_class<float,int>{}
        && my_class<int,int>{} == my_class<int,int>{};
}
```

Working [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hWY5hsYjW)

The extra benefit is that you can have all of your `// A few hundred LOCs` not mixed with your friend operators.

As explained on this wiki link - friend of base classes are also considered during ADL - so in this way you can happily have "Hidden Friend Idiom" in your template.

Comment: I know the question is pretty old -- but I just have similar problem and I've found the solution so why not share with others...